# Privileges page should have privileges listed in main page, not in sidebar

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, user-interface, privileges, privileges-page

Just a minor thing about the /privileges page: the list of privileges is in the sidebar. Usually, the important content is in the center, and the sidebar contains additional content that is less important. I actually thought the page had failed to load completely.

Here is an annotated screenshot describing my thought process. (Screenshot is from gaming but it appears to be the same layout on all the sites.)

[image]

Comment: The list *is* less important than the privilege description currently being read.

Comment: @MatthewRead it doesn't seem that way to me. If a user clicks their privileges link, aren't they most likely wanting to see what privileges they have?

Comment: @MatthewRead: The description may be more important, but it rather is about reputation than privileges. The word **priviledge** does not even appear before the second to last paragraph...

Comment: This will be implemented in the new privileges page rolling out this week!

Answer (score 5):

I sort of see that list on the right as something of a 'menu' of the privileges, and the page in question as something of an introductory page to that 'section' of the site.

As you rightly note, it's a minor thing, but I do think that last sentence could be worded better, perhaps:

> "Click on any privilege *listed to the right* to learn more about it"

Comment: Perhaps I jumped the gun, but the privileges page redesign which should rollout tomorrow eliminates the text that you reference

Comment: @JeremyTunnell Excellent! Thanks for the ping/update!